# Java Play! toJson ignore certain methods

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to serialize an object using toJson(object) and have the toJson-parser ignore certain methods?

We have a method in a User class  (getSocial - which is concerned with Facebook integration) that makes the toJson()-parsing fail - and we'd like it go ignore that method when serializing if possible.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate the object and rewrite it to `Map` or `List` with specified values only.

Note that if you are choosing your objects with Ebean it fetches whole object, also data, which shouldn't be fetched (as password or other credentials)

Comment: Thank you, I just ended up using @JsonIgnore though.

Answer (score 0):

use [fastjson & PropertyFilter](http://code.alibabatech.com/wiki/display/FastJSON/PropertyFilter):

Sample Code

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.PropertyFilter;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.SerializeWriter;

PropertyFilter filter = new PropertyFilter() {
    public boolean apply(Object source, String name, Object value) {
        return false;
    }
};

SerializeWriter out = new SerializeWriter();
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer(out);
serializer.getPropertyFilters().add(filter);

A a = new A();
serializer.write(a);

String text = out.toString();
Assert.assertEquals("{}", text);
```

PropertyFilter

```
PropertyFilter filter = new PropertyFilter() {
    public boolean apply(Object source, String name, Object value) {
        if("name".equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

SerializeWriter out = new SerializeWriter();
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer(out);
serializer.getPropertyFilters().add(filter);

A a = new A();
a.setName("chennp2008");
serializer.write(a);

String text = out.toString();
Assert.assertEquals("{\"name\":\"chennp2008\"}", text);
```

ValueObject:

```
public static class A {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```